# How do I iterate through selected cells in AgGrid?

Tags: ag-grid

I would like to delete the values in all selected cells when the user presses backspace or delete, how do I iterate through the selected cells?

I'm using React and Typescript

Answer (score 0):

The docs are out of date, this worked for me, in react / typescript

```js
(
  // The type of this is shown below, but is impossible to work with
  event: any
  // | CellKeyPressEvent<CountryLineProductRow>
  // | FullWidthCellKeyPressEvent<CountryLineProductRow>
) => {
  if (event.event.key === 'Backspace' || event.event.key === 'Delete') {
    event.api.getCellRanges().forEach((cellRange: CellRange) => {
      if (cellRange.startRow && cellRange.endRow) {
        const startRow = Math.min(
          cellRange.endRow.rowIndex,
          cellRange.startRow.rowIndex
        );

        const endRow = Math.min(
          cellRange.endRow.rowIndex,
          cellRange.startRow.rowIndex
        );

        cellRange.columns.forEach((column: Column) => {
          if (column.getColDef().editable) {
            for (
              let rowNumber = startRow;
              rowNumber <= endRow;
              rowNumber++
            ) {
              const model = event.api.getModel();
              const rowNode = model.rowsToDisplay[rowNumber];
              rowNode.setDataValue(column.getColDef().field, null);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```